# How to get WPT Autocompletebox selection item reference

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, wptoolkit

I am building a windows phone app where I m using the `Autocompletebox`. I am populating it dynamically through a web search api.

Now If the the user selects the specific item from the autocomplete box, how to get the reference of that specific object.

How I am using it is,

```
autocompbox.Itsemsource = List<MyClass objects>

Class MyClass
{
  string name;
  ...
  ..
}
```

name variable is bound on the automcompletebox text. Is there anyway to get which reference is selected? I am using the selectionchanged event, but I dont know the specific property which gives me the specific index of the itemsource.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

bind selectedItem in your ViewModel.

```
private string _selectedSearch;

    public string SelectedSearch
    {
        get { return _selectedSearch; }
        set
        {
            _selectedSearch = value;
            setSearch(_searchValue);
            RaisePropertyChanged(() => SelectedSearch);
        }
    }

private void setSearch(string searchValue){ // to do }
```

or acces directly like autocomplete.selectedItem

Comment: I dont want to to a search in the list again and find out which item is selected.are you saying autocomplete.selecteditem will return the myclass typed object?

Comment: You can just put a list<string> for itemsource for autocompleteBox. My exemple is for get SelectedItem and after set your list for see the item match

Comment: SelectionChanged event will help you in you don't use MVVM pattern

Comment: Thanks. It returned me the same type object that I can cast...It worked.